# How to create a executable jar file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, executable-jar

I have a selenium web driver program scripted in java in eclipse ide.
Now I need to run this program in other systems of same OS version(Windows).

Could you please provide the detailed step by step procedure to create executable jar file from eclipse and how to run it in other systems.

P.S: newbie here

Comment: Right-click the project, Export, then select "runnable jar file" from the Java section. Have you even tried anything?

Comment: yes,  I have tried this. The problem with this is the runnable file size is huge(60MB).  so I wont be send it to other systems via mail. That is the reason why I need to create executable jar file.

Comment: What do you think is the difference between a runnable jar file and an executable jar file? There is none. A runnable jar files includes all the dependencies that your code needs (such as selenium and every of its dependencies), which drives up the file size. You won't be able to reduce that size unless you figure out a way to minimize the amount of dependencies.

Comment: All that I know is executable jar comes with a Manifest file. and I have created executable jar file, the size has come down to 5 KB. now the problem is when I double click on the executable jar file inside eclipse it runs fine. When I run it by placing the file on desktop. it throws the error "A JNI error has occurred"

Comment: @dee, you need to distribute the dependencies. If you bundle them along your jar, it may get big (all selenium + its dependencies) are bundled together. If you have a single small jar without any dependencies, they won't be found on another computer. The whole package is really not to be sent by an email. You may still upload it somewhere (dropbox, aws s3, azure blob, ...) and let your colleges download it (60MB is not much)

Comment: Due to some constraints, mail is the only option that I have  to share the files. That is the reason why I need a executable jar file

Answer (score 0):

so, the first step after opening eclipse is to put your cursor on the "package explorer" and hitting the RBM (=Right Button Mouse) and clicking on "Export".

Here, you'll find a lot of folders, search "Java" folder and open it.

Select "Runnable JAR file" then "next".

in the new window opened, after "Launch configuration" there's a comboBox:

Select the project where the "MAIN" class is located.

In "Export destination" write the path of your (empty or inexistent) .jar file like that:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\executable.jar
```

Click "finish".

Now go to the path you entered before and create a new .bat or .cmd file end Edit it.

In this file you need to start the runnable jar file using java, write something like that:

```
@echo off
java -jar nameOfYourJarFile.jar
```

PS: the .jar and .cmd (or .bat) files must be in the same folder.

Comment: Before this - create runtime configiration - right-click on the project -> Properties -> Run/Debug, select main class if already not selected.

Comment: @Fabio La Greca , thanks for your detailed description. I have already done this and created runnable jar file.The problem with this is the runnable file size is huge(60MB). so I wont be send it to other systems via mail. That is the reason why I need to create executable jar file.
 
 
Due to some constraints, mail is the only option that I have to share the files. That is the reason why I need a executable jar file .

Comment: I have created executable jar file, the size has come down to 5 KB. now the problem is when I double click on the executable jar file inside eclipse it runs fine. When I run it by placing the file on desktop. it throws the error "A JNI error has occurred"

Comment: I have never found this problem. try to "recreate" the jar file selecting the radio button "package required libraries in generated JAR". remember that you need to start the software frome the .cmd/.bat